# Using the definite article vs no article

Tags: definite-articles

I come across many sentences that I fail to undertand why the authors have used the definite article, *the*.

For example, look at the following sentence. This is the first sentence (in introduction) of a journal article.

> The activities in a supply chain have the role of transforming raw materials into finished products that are
>   delivered from the supplier to the end customer.

I don't understand why the author has used *the* before *supplier* and *end customer*. I don't know who is the supplier or who is the end customer.

How about if we write in the following way. In fact, I have also seen such variants in the introductory paragraph of some artciles. Are the 1, 2, and 3 correct and carry the same meaning in this context?

1. *The activities in a supply chain have the role of transforming raw materials into finished products that are
   delivered from  a supplier to  an end customer.*
2. *The activities in a supply chain have the role of transforming raw materials into finished products that are
   delivered from suppliers to end customers.*
3. *The activities in a supply chain have the role of transforming raw materials into finished products that are
   delivered from supplier to end customer.*

I believe there are subtle differences that nonnative speakers can't understand. Could you reveal the mystery of *the*?

Comment: This question would be more appropriately asked on our sister site, [ELL.se], with two caveats: one, it will probably be closed as a duplicate of another question, because articles are a common source of confusion for English learners, and two, though *this* question has probably been asked and answered, a good litmus test for asking *anything* on any StackExchange site is: if you can imagine the answer to the question filling up a good essay or even a monograph, it's not a great question for SE. StackExchange wants definitive answers to factual questions, no studies or essays.

Comment: You must realize that every language has its idiosyncrasies. We use definite articles for some general statements where other languages might not, and vice versa. Why do we say in English "I wake up Fridays at seven," dropping the articles, where a Spanish speaker would absolutely include them ("Me levanto los viernes a las siete")? Asking *why* this is so is simply not productive. A better strategy would be to simply learn the language by observing *how* things are done and leave alone *why* they are done that way.

Comment: @Robusto For reasons unrelated to this question, I'm seeking a paper or text on the topic of language not being rational. Something that goes into detail, which provides both clear arguments and examples. Do you happen to know of such a work? If not, can you think of any technical terms or jargon which describe this well-established phenomenon or words which would necessarily or very likely be used in a treatment of it? Because the naive expectation (or sometimes *insistence*) that language must make sense is so widespread, I'm sure such a paper must exist.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you suggest, learning by observing is the key to become a writer on the field.

Comment: @Dan Bron, i hope to post on English Language Learners next time.

Comment: @DanBron: Sorry, I do not. About the closest I've come to this is a statement by John McWhorter in *Our Magnificent Bastard Tongue* that "No language makes perfect sense." I haven't read his [*What Language Is And What It Isn't*](http://www.amazon.com/What-Language-Isnt-Could-Be/dp/159240720X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1439815830&sr=8-1&keywords=What+Language+Is+%28And+What+It+Isn%27t+and+What+It+Could+Be%29)—yet—but that might have something on the order of what you're looking for, or at least point you in a direction.

Comment: @Robusto Thanks for the pointers. The reviews of *What Language Is* have already solved  one minor mystery which has been niggling me: why the more formally trained linguists here frequently repeat the refrain that "*spoken language is the real deal*", as opposed to written language, a mere shadow. Turns out (from those reviews) that it's the focus on and study of *written* language (which of course is more amenable to study, but also is slower to change), that gives rise to prescriptivist tendencies, in opposition to modern descriptivist linguistics.

Answer (score 2):

> The activities in a supply chain have the role of transforming raw materials into finished products that are delivered from **the** supplier to **the** end customer.

The definite articles in this sentence are not obligatory; but their use is perfectly reasonable.

You say:

> I don't know who is the supplier or who is the end customer.

I respond, Yes, you do. A supply chain is posited at the beginning of the sentence: *The activities in a supply chain*. Every supply chain includes, by definition, a final customer who receives products and a supplier who, well, supplies the products to the customer. Those are ***the*** final customer and ***the*** supplier of which the sentence speaks: not just any supplier or any customer but ***the*** customer and supplier involved in that particular supply chain.

Comment: Ohh. It sounds much interesting. I see the beauty of English here. @StoneyB